# preview multiple photos in the Grails GSP

Tags: grails

In my **Grails application** , I have **2 to 11** photos for each user saved as bytes in the DB ,i want to preview these images for users in the GSP  i need to know how to preview them in the GSP.

How could i do this?

the action in the controller :

```
def displayImage() {
    def photo = Photos.findAllByUsers(user)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return an array of images in controller:

```
def showImages() {
    def photos = Photos.findAllByUsers(user)
    [photos: photos]
}

def displayImage(photo) {
    def image = photo.photo // byte array
    response.setHeader('Content-length', image.length)
    response.contentType = 'image/png' // or the appropriate image content type
    response.outputStream << image
    response.outputStream.flush()
}
```

and show it in a *showImages.gsp* file as:

```
<g:each var="photo" in="${photos}">
     <img src="${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'displayImage', params: ['photo': photo])}"/>
</g:each>
```

Comment: not working `Class:groovy.lang.MissingMethodExceptionMessage:Error evaluating expression [photo.encodeBase64()] `

Comment: look at it: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html

Comment: did you define function encodeBase64() in domain class Photos basing on the post I've send you? if so, show me a code.

Comment: isn't it a predefined method same as `encodeAsHTML` ?

Comment: true. Moreover currently we are trying to execute encodeBase64() on Photos object, but we should do it on its binary property. Show me your Photos domain class.

Comment: `class Photos {
 Date dateCreated
 byte [] photo
 Date lastUpdated}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101632/discussion-between-majkelo-and-sherif).

Comment: i made clean and restarted my application and i didn't get that error , but the still can't be shown , i found in the 'view page source' that this `<img src="data:image/png;base64,${photo.photo.encodeBase64()}"/>`  was translated to `<img src="/myApp/images">` any idea why that happened ? from where `images` came i haven't anything named `images` in my application.

Comment: i did as you show me but unfortunately , i can't show the pictures ,here is a screen shot of the show page [link] (http://s11.postimg.org/yz28u5sv7/image.jpg)

Comment: What's the source code of the selected fragment of this website?